# How to create multidimensional list of different sizes in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to input list(matrix) of different sizes(columns) such as
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[7,8,9,10]]
How to take the input?**strong text**

Comment: Is `a` an example output? Is the input simply concerning the dimensions and sizes of the list(s) or contents too?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @fishcakes 'a' is the input

Comment: And what would an example output be? It is hard to help without more details about what you are trying to accomplish